# Any advice for sending a request to a website from Python?

Tags: python, html, css, urllib2, bioinformatics

```
def align_sequences(IDs):
    import webbrowser
    import urllib,urllib2
    url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/align/'
    params = {'query':IDs}
    data = urllib.urlencode(params)
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    job_url = response.geturl()
    webbrowser.open(job_url)
align_sequences('Q4PRD1 Q7LZ61')
```

With this function I want to open 'http://www.uniprot.org/align/', request the protein sequences with IDs Q4PRD1 and Q7LZ61 to be aligned, and then open the website in my browser.

Initially it seems to be working fine - running the script will open the website and show the alignment job to being run. However, it will keep going forever and never actually finish, even if I refresh the page. If I input the IDs in the browser and hit 'align' it works just fine, taking about 8 seconds to align.

I am not familiar with the differences between running something directly from a browser and running it from Python. Do any of you have an idea of what might be going wrong?

Thank you :-)
~Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is in javascript. If you look at the html-code of button `Align` you can see

```
onclick="UniProt.analytics('AlignmentSubmissionPage', 'click', 'Submit align'); submitAlignForm();"
```

`UniProt.analytics()` and `submitAlignForm()` some javascript magic. This magic in `js-compr.js2013_11` file.

You can view this file using http://jsbeautifier.org/ and then do on python what do javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You have to click `align` button. You can't do this with `webbrowser` though. One option is to use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/align/'
ids = 'Q4PRD1 Q7LZ61'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
q = driver.find_element_by_id('alignQuery')
q.send_keys(ids)
btn = driver.find_element_by_id("sequence-align-submit")
btn.click()
```